How do I add tags to the 'tags' property of a file programmatically so it shows in windows explorer?
I want a quick way to be able to tag multiple image files all at once in Windows 11.
For example, how can I programmatically add tags to files such that they show up here:

I was looking at Darktable as it has apparently useful tagging functionality, but I think the tags are stored externally in another file or database, not the file's 'tags' property as shown above.

According to Microsoft, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-add-tag-into-a-picture-by-command-line/f1b70cc4-4263-48cb-86f5-aa75f9d15edf, "The only way I know to batch add/edit tags in Command Line is to use ExifTool by Phil Harvey, that has a command line interface to process your image files "

That tool rings a bell...I think I may have come across that years ago, then forgot. Thx for the tip.

ExifTool, https://www.exiftool.org/, has been quite useful to me. It's a command-line tool, as you need, though there is an additional GUI, too. As with any third-party software, check at VirusTotal.com after downloading.
